# Web Push Service Ocasionally Bugs

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Not sure what I'm doing wrong with my service worker implementation.

Ideally, I'm facing problems with either "The Website has been refreshed in the background" with this one.

I didn't have this problem before with the code, but once the Push Notification subscribers count got to around 600 it started to cause issues with every single one of them.

```js
var init = { method: 'GET',
             headers: {
                "Content-Type" : "application/javascript"
             },
              mode: 'cors',
              cache: 'no-cache' 
           };
var worker = self;
var the_endpoint = '';

fetch(the_endpoint, init ).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(data){
  worker.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        worker.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
          body                : data.body,
          icon                : data.icon,
          requireInteraction  : true
        })
    );
  });

  if( data.link != '' ) {
    worker.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
      event.notification.close();
      var url = data.link;
      event.waitUntil(
          clients.matchAll({
            type: 'window'
          })
              .then(function(windowClients) {
                for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                  var client = windowClients[i];
                  if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
                    return client.focus();
                  }
                }
                if (clients.openWindow) {
                  return clients.openWindow(url);
                }
              })
      );
    });
  }
});
```

Attempt 2 that doesn't have the background refresh issue, but doesn't always work.

```js
var init = { method: 'GET',
             headers: {
                "Content-Type" : "application/javascript"
             },
              mode: 'cors',
              cache: 'no-cache' 
           };
var worker = self;
var the_endpoint = '';

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
      fetch(the_endpoint, init).then(function (response) {
        return response.json().then(function (data) {

          var response = self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
            body: data.body,
            icon: data.icon,
            requireInteraction: true
          });

          if (data.link != '') {
            worker.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
              event.notification.close();
              var url = data.link;
              event.waitUntil(
                  clients.matchAll({
                    type: 'window'
                  }).then(function (windowClients) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
                      var client = windowClients[i];
                      if (client.url === url && 'focus' in client) {
                        return client.focus();
                      }
                    }
                    if (clients.openWindow) {
                      return clients.openWindow(url);
                    }
                  })
              );
            });
          }

          return response;
        });
      })
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this often occurs is the promise returned to `event.waitUntil()` didn't resolve with a notification being shown.

An example that might show the default "The Website has been refreshed in the background" notification:

```
function handlePush() {
  // BAD: The fetch's promise isn't returned
  fetch('/some/api')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    // BAD: the showNotification promise isn't returned
    showNotification(data.title, {body: data.body});
  });
}

self.addEventListener(function(event) {
   event.waitUntil(handlePush());
});
```

Instead you could should write this as:

```
function handlePush() {
  // GOOD
  return fetch('/some/api')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    // GOOD
    return showNotification(data.title, {body: data.body});
  });
}

self.addEventListener(function(event) {
   const myNotificationPromise = handlePush();
   event.waitUntil(myNotificationPromise);
});
```

The reason this is all important is that browsers wait for the promise passed into event.waitUntil to resolve / finish so they know the service worker needs to be kept alive and running.

When the promise resolves for a push event, chrome will check that a notification has been shown and it falls into a race condition / specific circumstance as to whether Chrome shows this notification or not. Best bet is to ensure you have a correct promise chain.

I put some extra notes on promises on this post (See: 'Side Quest: Promises' https://gauntface.com/blog/2016/05/01/push-debugging-analytics)